# Submit form remaining the same page in Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, angular6

I have an issue in a Login Form. When credentials are not valids the form is reload so I cannot show errors send by the response's server because the reloading issue.

I have tried with preventDefault but it does not work.

My form is this:

```
    <mat-card class="login-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
        <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ error }}
        </div>
      </mat-card-header>
      <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="loginSubmit()">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput
                     type="text"
                     placeholder="Correo electrónico"
                     formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput
                     type="password"
                     placeholder="Contraseña"
                     formControlName="password">
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <input matInput
                  type="submit" 
                  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"
                  color="primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </form>
    </mat-card>
```

And my controller, where loginSubmit is, is this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  returnUrl: string;
  error: string;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Estoy aquí amigos");
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  loginSubmit() {
    let email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
    let password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.authService.login(email, password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("Dentro de data");
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          alert(error);
          this.error = "Error de autenticación";
          console.log("Dentro de error");
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          console.log("bien");
        }
      );
  }
}
```

loginForm function above is called when user click submit button and it calls a Service that POST the login action. When login is not success then I would like to show errors in form HTML page but login form is reloading so I cannot do it.

Lastly, the AuthService is this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.API_URL}/api/login`, { email, password })
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          }

          return user;
        })
      );
  }

  logout() {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.API_URL}/api/logout`, null)
      .pipe(
        map(resp => {
          // remove user from local storage to log user out
          localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');

          return true;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Where login is.

Comment: I think there are some detais missing in your question to help us understand : does the server respond with an error code (like 400+ or 500+) when there is an error ? Also, you don't show your authService. Is it correctly emitting (or transfering) error ? Are you using HttpClient in it?

Comment: @Pac0 The server is a Laravel API and return a 401: `return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);` I have added AuthService code. Thanks.

Comment: console.log the value of 'this.loginForm.invalid' on submit function because as you said the page is reloading that means the 'if' condition for invalid login isn't getting satisfied

Comment: You could also try turning on route tracing to see what the route is when the page reloads. That may help you determine what's going wrong.

Comment: @sanky the form is valid, I mean the email is a valid email and the password is a valid password but this email/password does not exists so the server send an Authentication 401 Error and I would like to show that in form page but I cannot because reloading :( Thanks

Comment: ok ! I got confused with this
` // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }`

Comment: I have fixed the (stupid) issue. The problem was in an error interceptor where it reloads the current page where a 401 error is triggered. Thanks for your comments.